# phpmyadmin and firefox in xampp

Tags: firefox, phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed xampp in my computer and I use Google Chrome to open locally my websites without any problem, but when I use Firefox to open phpMyadmin the URL is changed in "/phpmyadmin/index.php#PMAURL:server=1&target=main.php&token=b92fecc65da8847f71a421e37bf5151f" and I get only the list of databases, that is only the left column of the phpMyadmin page.

I "googled" a lot but I did get any answer to that problem.

Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot,
Nino V

Comment: What Firefox and phpMyAdmin versions do you have?

Answer (score -1):

You need to be using

```
http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/
```

or

```
localhost/phpmyadmin/
```